# Get and parse string from json to php

Tags: php, json

I got json response with the following format :

```
 "/Date(1234)/"
```

How do I get the numbers only as string (1234) in php ?

thanks

Comment: If you have JSON, you need to use `json_decode()`

Comment: It's not a valid json string

Comment: Post the actual JSON data that you've received.

Answer (score 1):

```
$dateonly = "/Date(1234)/";
echo $dateonly = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "",$dateonly);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is JSON, or at least not a valid one. Nonetheless, you can extract numbers like this:

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!', stripslashes("/Date(1234)/"), $output);
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

This format `/Date(1234)/` usually called JSON Date Format. It contain unixtime with miliseconds. So, when you extract the number you need to divide it to `1000` to get the unixtime and process it in PHP.
Here I give a function to extract the date and convert it to **PHP** `DateTime` Object

```
function parseJSDate($jsDateObject)
{
    $dateTime = null;
    if (preg_match("/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//", $jsDateObject, $match)) {
        if (isset($match[1]) && is_numeric($match[1])) {
            $timestamp = (int) $match[1];
            $dateTime  = new \DateTime();
            $dateTime->setTimestamp($timestamp / 1000);
        }
    }

    return $dateTime;
}

$date = parseJSDate("/Date(1224043200000)/");
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```